# How can I pull all work items currently or previously associated with a Sprint in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, iteration, devops

I am attempting to retrieve all work items currently or previously associated with a given Iteration from Azure DevOps, either through an in-system query or through the API. I need this information to calculate sprint predictability metrics.

As far as I can tell, ADO only stores the latest Iteration in the work items fields, so the API call to ask for tickets associated with a Past iteration does not include any tickets that may have been moved to a different iteration mid-sprint. Likewise, they query options do not allow for something like a "was" operator to test for work items with may have met the criteria in the past.

Short of pulling each work item history individually through the API and creating my own iteration timeline for all tickets in the system, how can I get this information?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. You have to use the "was ever" operator in the iteration path. To do so, you have to query for it using the [WIQL-Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/wiql-syntax?view=azure-devops).

So you'll have to add

```
...

AND (
        EVER (
            [System.IterationPath] = @currentIteration('[YourTeam]\... <id:...>'))
```

to the `WHERE` part of the query.

If you want to see an extended example, look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-date-or-current-iteration?view=azure-devops).